# add values of identical dicts in a list

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list of identical dicts (same keys, same number of keys..) ..like this:

```
 mydict_list =   [
        {'win32': [2, 45], 'https': [2, 13], 'nofollow': [3, 45], 'href': [4, 847]},
        {'win32': [0, 5], 'https': [0, 13], 'nofollow': [1, 5], 'href': [2, 87]}
    ]
```

I want to create one dict that has the same keys and values added up nicely....like this:

```
{'win32': [2, 50], 'https': [2, 26], 'nofollow': [4, 50], 'href': [6, 934]}
```

Is there an elegant way to do it?

This is what I have working. It works and is readable also:

```
keys = list(mydict_list[0].keys())
final_dict = {item: [] for item in keys}

for k in list(final_dict.keys()):
    v0 = v1 = 0
    for d in mydict_list:
        for kk, v in d.items():
             if k == kk:
                 v0 += v[0]
                 v1 += v[1]
                 final_dict.update({k: [v0, v1]})
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what exactly is the problem with it? What is inelegant about it?

Comment: Are all values two-element lists?

Comment: added what I have working so far. Yes, all values are two-element lists. And, the number of dicts in mydict_list could vary.

Answer (score 1):

Short approach:

```
lst = [
    {'win32': [2, 45], 'https': [2, 13], 'nofollow': [3, 45], 'href': [4, 847]},
    {'win32': [0, 5], 'https': [0, 13], 'nofollow': [1, 5], 'href': [2, 87]}
]

res = lst[0]   # start with the 1st dict
for d in lst[1:]:
    for k, v in d.items():
        res[k] = list(map(sum, zip(v, res[k])))
print(res)
```

The output:

```
{'win32': [2, 50], 'https': [2, 26], 'nofollow': [4, 50], 'href': [6, 934]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a dictionary comprehension on this to make it more "pythonic" (though readability goes down significantly)

```
 d1=[
    {'win32': [2, 45], 'https': [2, 13], 'nofollow': [3, 45], 'href': [4, 847]},
    {'win32': [0, 5], 'https': [0, 13], 'nofollow': [1, 5], 'href': [2, 87]}
]
```

Can do it in a a two-liner (and should be mostly generic for almost all cases). Assuming that all the keys are the same across each dictionary in the array.

```
d2={key:[d[key] for d in d1] for key in d1[0].keys()}
d3={key:[sum(d3) for d3 in list(map(list,zip(*d2[key])))] for key in d1[0].keys()}

print(d3)

{'win32': [2, 50], 'https': [2, 26], 'nofollow': [4, 50], 'href': [6, 934]}
```

**The Explanation**

Dictionary comprehensions allow you to collapse your array so that we can work with each key individually. 
In the first step, we create `d2` which is d1 rearranged by key.

Once you have that in place, `d3` the `list-map` re-arranges the array so that you can sum each list element wise using the built-in sum as part of a list comprehension.

If data was stored as a numpy array, this process would probably go significantly faster (as is, it's a bit memory inefficient).